# How to extract cell format (bold, italic, ...) from an Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, format

I'm trying to extract from an Excel file the content of a cell (essentially text) and the format of the text. The Excel I am dealing with looks like the screenshot below :

[image: screenshot of excel]

Texts in cells may be bold, italic or stroke and I need to extract the text and the format into a python string. For example, if a cell contains :

> - line 1
> - **line 2**
> - *line 3*

I would like to obtain a string Python that's look like :

```
- line 1 /n- **line 2**/n- *line 3**
```

in order to get the text and the format information.

I've tried to find a solution using openpyxl, but it seems that it is only possible to apply and not extract format cell. Library xlrd seems not fitted for xlsx. I am currently trying with pyexcel library.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: if the excelfile is in xlsx-format, you could give a try reading it as xml (in essence xlsx is a propiatary xml format). Overall: it's always very bad idea to use markup in excel to give some status to the value of a cell, especially if there are multiple values in a single cell. If it's possible: consider changing the excelfile that is being used so that you have 1 value max in a cell, it will make working with it a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can import Font from openpyxl and check if a cell is written in bold by using `cell.font.bold`, it gives a True or False.

```
cell=sheet[A2]
bold_status=cell.font.bold
italic_status=cell.font.italic
```

More info on the fonts in openpyxl: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/api/openpyxl.styles.fonts.html

Comment: Note that this works properly only if the entire content of the cell is bold/not bold.

Comment: Is there a way to extract partially bold text from excel cells. I'm exactly searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using openpyxl you can extract both the style of the entire cell (as shown in a previous answer) and parts of the text in each cell if you set the `rich_text` flag to `True` when loading the workbook.

Here is an example in python 3.10 that prints out all italicized text:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import CellRichText, TextBlock


# The 'rich_text=True' parameter is required otherwise the cells are 
workbook = load_workbook('trash/test.xlsx', rich_text=True)

# Assume you're working with the first sheet
sheet = workbook.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        # Check if the entire cell is italicized
        if cell.font.italic:
        print(f"Cell {cell.coordinate} is completely italicized: {cell.value}")

        # cell.value will either be CellRichText or str, with CellRichText having more formatting that needs to be checked.
        if isinstance(cell.value, CellRichText):
            for text_block in cell.value:
                # Ensure it's a text block not a plain string, and that it is in fact italicized
                if isinstance(text_block, TextBlock) and text_block.font.italic:
                    print(f"Cell {cell.coordinate} contains italicized text: {text_block.text}")

workbook.close()
```

This example will print out all the italicized text and what cell that text is in. For completely italicized cells it will print out a single entry for that cell, for cells that are interspersed with formatting it will print out multiple entries for every block of text that is italicized. This means that if a cell is completely italicized and has some other text formatting in it it will print out multiple entries with some caveats.

If you have "*this is* ***an*** *example*" in cell A1 you get this output from the script:

```
Cell A1 is completely italicized: this is an example
Cell A1 contains italicized text: an
Cell A1 contains italicized text:  example
```

- 1 for the entire cell
- the "this is " seems to be skipped
- 1 for the bolded italicized "an"
- 1 for the italicized " example"