# How to test if a list contains Italics or bold text?

Tags: python

I have an exel file with names. Some are stored as italics other some bold or normal.
The Italics names is "feminin" male is normal text and unisex names are in bold.
The list is long about 6500 names. I would like to be able to sort out the different types according to the way they are stored in the Exel file.

Like 
`Print("namn()", 'Female')`
`print(namn(), 'Male')`

```
file_name = 'Namn.xlsx' #xlsx file to open
sheet =  'Sheet1' # name of sheet

import pandas as pan
namn = pan.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet)
print(namn.head(10), 'Female')  # Print 10 first names in exel file

# problem 1. female names are Italics in the original file but gets printed as regular.
# unisex names are in bold and get printed as normal text in the output.
#
# problem 2. How do I sort out Italics names and Bold names stored in the file.

# 10 first names in the exel file

#      Abbe (Normal text in exel file)
#       Abe (Normal text in exel file)
#       Ada (Italics in exel file) 
#      Adam (Normal text in exel file)
#     Adana (Italics in exel file)
#   Adanita (Italics in exel file)
#      Adde (Bold in exel file)
#   Addison (Bold in exel file)
#     Adele (Italics in exel file)
#     Adolf (Normal text in exel file)
```

Comment: [You cannot do it with `pandas`, but with `openpyxl`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176906/how-to-extract-cell-format-bold-italic-from-an-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904470/checking-for-particular-style-using-python-docx) question should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly i don't know a way to do it with pandas at the moment, having to dig more into pandas on my own. 
however you could use `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl as xl

file_path = 'absolute/path/to/your.xlsx'

wb = xl.load_workbook(file_path)
ws = wb.active 

#changing to other worksheets:
#ws = wb["Title of the Worksheet"]

a1 = ws['A1']
print(a1.font)# lists the params of font ( i for italic ) 
print(a1.font.i == True)
```

Just tested it with an .xlsx containing a single worksheet and an italic string in A1.